# python flask render_template and another return value

Tags: python, flask

I use Python flask for my web application. the application provide a CSV file to download. CSV file is the response in below code block. Also I need to send a variable to html template. How can I have two return value?

```
@application.route("/log_analysis", methods=['POST'])
def get_response():
    output='The result of your query :  '+str(i-1)+' . The full report is downloaded automatically.'
    cw.writerows(csv_rows)
    response = make_response(si.getvalue())
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = f"attachment; filename={return_file_name}"
    response.headers["Content-type"] = "text/csv"
    
    return render_template('base.html',output=output)
    return response, 200
```

The output will be shown in the html but the response in the second return doesn't work.

Comment: The first `return` exits your `get_response` method.

Comment: You want 2 returns from your function when the method is POST, or you want one reponse for method=POST and another one for method=GET?

Comment: I need 2 returns from my function when the method is POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your question, I think what you are looking for is something like flash messages. The variable `content` you are passing in, is just text and used to display a message.

---

#### Flash messages

You'll need to set this up in your `base.html` or whatever template you are rendering.

Template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<main>
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
    {% if messages %}
        {% for category, message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}

{% block content %}{% endblock %}

</main>
</body>

</html>
```

---

```py
from flask import render_template, url_for, flash, redirect

@application.route("/log_analysis", methods=['POST'])
def get_response():
    output=f'The result of your query :  {i-1} . The full report is downloaded automatically.'
    cw.writerows(csv_rows)
    response = make_response(si.getvalue())
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = f"attachment; filename={return_file_name}"
    response.headers["Content-type"] = "text/csv"
    flash(output,'success')
    
    return response, 200
```

---

You can also try and do something like `alerts` in html template